# caddy webserver - website domin configuration

Tags: html, web, webserver, caddy, caddyfile

I want to use Caddy webserver in docker container, it works locally correctly, but when I set the domain name in caddy configuration, I can not connect to my web pages.

Below is simple caddy configuration /etc/caddy/Caddyfile

```
# domain name.
test.com
# Set this path to your site's directory.                                                                                                                     root * /srv  
# Enable the static file server.                                                                                                                              file_server
```

also I just run : caddy run in the container.

```
ad0497d132d0        caddy:latest        "/bin/sh"           28 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes       443/tcp, 2019/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8090->80/tcp   friendly_banzai
```

Comment: Please format your question to make it more readable